# How to get value from ngModel?

Tags: angular

I have this form:

```
    <form id="login-form" class="text-left" (ngSubmit)="submitLogin()">
      <div class="login-form-main-message"></div>
                <div class="main-login-form">
                    <div class="login-group">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="lg_username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lg_username" name="lg_username" placeholder="username"  [(ngModel)]="username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="lg_password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="lg_password" name="lg_password" placeholder="password"  [(ngModel)]="password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="login-button"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" ></i>LOGIN</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

In component i have this:

```
  submitLogin(){
          // Variable to hold a reference of addComment/updateComment

      }
```

I have login component:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { LoginService } from '../services/login.service';
import { Login } from '../model/login'
@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: 'login-form',

})
export class LoginComponent {
  // Constructor with injected service
      constructor(
          private commentService: LoginService
          ){}
      // Local properties
      private model = new Login('', '');

      submitLogin(){
          // Variable to hold a reference of addComment/updateComment
            alert('aaaa');
      }


}
```

Now what i want is to get value in `submitLogin()` from ngModel and then handle that values what ever i want. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the value from the form:

```
<form #form="ngForm" id="login-form" class="text-left" (ngSubmit)="submitLogin(form.value)">
```

Comment: and how can i access those values in component? because when i use right now : this.username i get an error

Comment: `submitLogin(values) { console.log(values); }`

Comment: tnx .. thats it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use reference variable to get access your `ngModel`

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="..." #name="ngModel">
```

And then use this variable if your template.

More details here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#ref-vars